# Traduction du mot néerlandais « glad »

Tags: mathématiques, néerlandais

Je cherche une traduction de « glad ». Ce mot se traduit littéralement par « lisse ».

Je l’entends souvent à la fac. On l’emploie pour éviter l’approfondissment des matières que l’on ne peut pas encore comprendre.

Par exemple, la théorie des probabilités  repose sur les tribus, c’est un truc que je ne connais pas, mais il semble qu'il s'agisse d’une famille d’ensembles munie des lois ensemblistes. On a aussi besoin de connaissance des *mesures*
Il est cependant souhaitable de comprendre dans les grandes lignes des grandeurs aléatoires avant d’étudier en profondeur les *mesures*. L’étude des mesures est trop abstraite pour quelqu’un qui ébauche ces études de mathématiques, et est donc, chez nous, sauté pour être disséqué deux ans plus tard.

Au lieu de dire qu’une grandeur aléatoire est mesurable, on dit souvent qu’elle « jouit des bonnes propriétés » ou qu’elle « se comporte comme il faut » ou qu’elle est *lisse*. J’aimerais savoir comment cela s’exprime en français.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lorsqu'on étudie des théories mathématiques sans connaître les concepts sur lesquels elles se fondent, et qu'on ne veut pas non plus approfondir, la seule expression que je connais en Français est "possédant de bonnes propriétés".

Dans ton exemple, il est **strictement impossible** d'expliquer la notion de mesurabilité des variables aléatoires à quelqu'un qui n'a jamais été confronté à la théorie de la mesure. Il est fréquent, par exemple, d'apprendre les probabilités sans en étudier les fondements, c'est-à-dire d'utiliser l'intégrale de Riemann et pas la théorie de Lebesgue. Dans ce cas, on passe entièrement sous silence les propriétés de mesurabilité des variables aléatoires, les notions de construction des mesures ou d'intégration abstraite.

Si le professeur essaie de vous dire que les variables aléatoires que vous manipulez vérifient des hypothèses trop compliquées pour que vous les compreniez, je te suggère :

- ou bien de dire la bonne hypothèse, quitte à ne pas comprendre ("X" est F-mesurable")
- ou bien de prendre le temps d'expliquer la situation, par exemple : "X vérifie certaines hypothèses de régularité qui sont vérifiées par presque toutes les variables aléatoires usuelles, et que je ne détaillerai pas", ou encore "le comportement de X n'est pas trop pathologique".
- ou bien de ne rien dire du tout, ce qui est finalement le mieux.

Si tu veux utiliser absolument un adjectif pour traduire "glad", je te conseille de le traduire par "bon", comme dans "une bonne variable aléatoire". Il suffit alors que tu expliques quelque part que par "bon", tu veux dire "satisfaisant à certaines conditions que je ne connais pas". C'est une solution que j'ai moi même parfois rencontrée dans mes cours de maths : le prof nous parlait de "bons espaces fonctionnels" pour dire "des espaces un peu trop compliqués pour vous, vous apprendrez ça plus tard" :)

Dans tous les cas, **je te déconseille d'utiliser l'adjectif "lisse".** En mathématiques, dire qu'une fonction (ou une variable aléatoire) est "lisse" possède un contenu mathématique précis : on utilise souvent cela pour parler de fonctions infiniment différentiables. D'ailleurs, de nombreux cours de mathématiques avancées portent l'intiulé "Analyse non-lisse", traduction littérale de l'anglais "non-smooth analysis". Si tu dis qu'une variable aléatoire est "lisse", c'est en ce sens qu'on le comprendra et ça n'aura rien à voir avec ton cours de probabilité élémentaires !

*appendice mathématique, où j'essaie de vulgariser la notion de mesurabilité.*

En gros, en probabilités, on sélectionne les événements qui sont envisageables et on rejette les autres. C'est pour cela que la notion de tribu correspond à la notion d'information : une tribu, c'est l'ensemble de tout ce qui peut arriver. Si dans votre tribu, il n'y a rien, cela veut dire que vous ne pouvez avoir que très peu d'information sur ce qui peut arriver : il y a pas mal d'événements que vous ne pouvez pas connaître. Si votre tribu est très grosse, cela veut dire le contraire : quoi qu'il arrive, vous pourrez discerner des événements qui paraissent très proches, et que vous ne pourriez pas discerner si votre tribu avait été plus faible.
Dire qu'une grandeur aléatoire est mesurable par rapport à une tribu, cela veut dire que toutes les valeurs qu'elle peut prendre correspondent à des événements que vous pouvez connaître, c'està-dire des événements qui sont dons votre tribu. Une variable aléatoire peut être mesurable par rapport à une tribu, mais pas pr rapport à une autre ! C'est la modélisation du fait suivant : si vous disposez d'un thermomètre, la température qu'il affiche vous donne des informations sur le temps qu'il fait ("tribu météo"), mais pas sur les résultats des prochaines élections présidentielles ("tribu politique").

Espérant vous avoir éclairé :)
bonne journée

Comment: +1 pour "possédant de bonnes propriétés". Trés utilisé en laboratoire de mathématiques. On utilise aussi "gentil(le)", plus informellement.